# Best USB drive to run OS on

Tags: usb, osx

I was planning to install an OS on a USB flash drive so I can run another OS out of my classic Windows 7.
I was searching for USB drives with high Read and Write speeds, but then I read on an article that that’s not what you have to look at if you want to run OSs on that flash drive.

---

### Question

What are the specs I have to consider in order to get the best out of my flash drive?
I was thinking about trying out MacOS Sierra, what do you think it’s best?

---

### My pick

I found [this USB](http://www.kingston.com/en/usb/personal_business/hxs3) by Kingston as a valid candidate, but then read on [this article](http://www.legitreviews.com/hyperx-savage-usb-3-1-flash-drive-review_175374/3) that it’s not...

Comment: Do you have a laptop or a desktop? Also, what kind of capacity were you looking at?

Comment: I have a laptop, an Asus, i5 @E.Nunn

Comment: I would be excessively cautious about running a Hackintosh from a USB, on PC hardware. To get a functioning Hackintosh with ZERO problems is a difficult feat on a desktop with Hard drives, let alone a laptop booting from a USB.

Comment: That’s all I have tho @E.Nunn I can just get a new USB, not a new computer unfortunately

Comment: Sure, I wasn't suggesting a new computer, I was just specifically wary of Hackintoshes, as, despite the technical problems, they are illegal anyhow. http://lockergnome.com/2012/02/24/are-hackintosh-computers-legal/ . To be fair, Apple are hardly likely to come knocking on your door, but it's just the ethics of breaking the EULA.

Comment: Sure they are. However what do you think about that USB I found?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63401/discussion-between-e-nunn-and-fet).